# sqlcipher compilar plugin no windows

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Como eu faço para compilar o plugin no windows?

Estou fazendo assim:

- Git Clone `sqlcipher` - `C:\sqlcipher`
- instalado `MINGW32` - `C:\MINGW32`
- instalado `msys` - `C:\MINGW32\msys\1.0`
- instalado `tcltk-8.4.1-1`- `C:\MINGW32\bin` `tclsh84` renomeado `tclsh.exe`
- instalado `Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1f` - `C:\OpenSSL-Win32`

Agora os comando:

1- executo `C:\MINGW32\msys\1.0\msys.exe`

2 - No mysys.exe, comando: `cd c:sqlcipher`

3 - `./configure --prefix=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlcipher CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"`

Retorna o erro:

./configure: line 470: sed: command not found
./configure: line 469: expr:command not found
./configure: line 470: sed: command not found
./configure: line 484: sed: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:

Fiz o Download do `MinGW get` com `MinGw-developer-tookit`.